# How to search through .rxdata

Tags: macos, finder

I have a folder with a lot of .rxdata and .txt files.

If I search for a word, with cmd-f, when I'm in the folder only .txt results are included.

If I change the extension of a .rxdata file to .txt nothing happens. However if I open a .rxdata, copy the text, create a new document, paste the text and save it as .txt, making a new identical document with different extension, it works fine.

Is there a way to make cmd+f to search through .rxdata, without having to create duplicate .txt file for each (there about 500 files, so it would be very long)